# Add mask to camera

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins, flutter-plugin

I am new on Flutter and trying to do an app that use camera. So, everything works fine and I am using **image_picker** lib. Now, I need to add a mask for my user to capture using this mask to position the document (like a overlay) but I can't find anywhere saying how to do that. Does anyone know if it's possible using this lib to do it?

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the image_picker can do what you want to do.

Instead of that, you could use the [Camera package](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) and put your overlay and the preview of camera in a Stack widget

Answer (score 2):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/camera_camera 
It provide `imageMask` attribute 
example code https://github.com/gabuldev/camera_camera/tree/master/example/lib 
code snippet

```
Camera(
       mode: CameraMode.normal,
       imageMask: CameraFocus.rectangle(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                ),
     )
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: At the moment, camera_camera version 2.0.0 has removed the mask option from its build. Older versions can still work, but they have some issues with null-safety that may result in incompatible dependencies.